# Sitecore 8.1 experience editor is very slow

Tags: sitecore, sitecore8, sitecore8.1

We upgraded the sitecore from 7.2 to 8.1. Since the upgrade the content authors are complaining that the experience editor performance is much slower than previous version. It takes long time to load and also editing experience is very slow as well.

For now I've reverted back to SHEER UI version of experience editor by updating experienceeditor.config.

I read this blog post below but option 1 and 2 states "be aware that there are significant consequences...".

http://kamsar.net/index.php/2015/02/sitecore-8-experience-editor-performance-optimization/

Has any one experience this issue? And have any recommendation for the fix?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you add the link to the blog post you mentioned in the question?
Sitecore 8.0 Experience Editor was slow...and 8.1 improves that... but compared to SheerUI from pre-8.0, it may be a bit slower because it's loading SPEAK components individually.

Comment: What type of latency is between your authors and your CM server(s)?  Minimizing latency and getting your authors as close as possible to your CM servers will greatly improve their experience.

Comment: @SeanHolmesby, yep added now.

Comment: @MattGartman, sitecore is hosted in azure web apps.

Comment: I've found `optimizeCompilations` to be quite optimal during development, but just to be safe I disable it as part of my deployment scripts. It's only ever caused a problem once that I can remember.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reverting to SheerUI is probably an option you could consider... we know it works faster that the SPEAK UI, so it's a quick win to help out your content editors at the moment.

However Sitecore is moving towards SPEAK, and so I'm not sure how long the SheerUI interface will still keep up with the new features of the Experience Editor.

In addition to the pre-compilation of Views, you COULD attempt Kam's optimization, but as he mentioned, there could be significant issues that come about because of it.

I would also have a look into some other possibilities for speeding it up, like:-

- Use the application cache to increase the performance of loading the
  Experience Editor ribbon. - (https://doc.sitecore.net/Sitecore%20Experience%20Platform/The%20editing%20tools/Improve%20the%20performance%20of%20the%20Experience%20Editor%20ribbon)
- Using ContentSearch instead of Fast Query for the 'My Items' count - (http://mikael.com/2015/12/speading-up-the-sitecore-experience-editor/), or even turning off the count altogether (http://sitecoreblog.alexshyba.com/hidden_gem_of_sitecore_page_editor/). **UPDATE:** Sitecore now has a Support DLL for this. (https://kb.sitecore.net/en/Articles/2015/12/04/14/31/549951.aspx)
- Customize or even disable the `SuggestedTestsCountRequest`. - (http://blog.horizontalintegration.com/2015/07/05/sitecore8-experience-editor-slow/)